# Search two tables, and update search result in single form

Tags: php, mysql

Here my `table1` and `table2`

```
table1
+-------+-------------+---------+
| Nomor |   Name      |   Age   |
+-------+-------------+---------+ 
|  a1   | Supar       | 25      |
|  a2   | Rambo       | 23      |
+-------+-------------+---------+

table2
+-------+-------------+---------+
| Nomor |   Name      |   Age   |
+-------+-------------+---------+ 
|  b1   | Boneng      | 28      |
|  b2   | Dennyius    | 32      |
+-------+-------------+---------+
```

i want to make search form by `$Nomor` to update data `$Name` or `$Age` from two tables.

here my code to search n fetch data:

```
if(isset($_POST['Search'])) {

    $NoMohon = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Nomor']);

    //query database
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor' union SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor'");

    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
            $Nomor = $rows['Nomor'];
            $Name = $rows['Name'];
            $Age = $rows['Age'];
        }
    } else {
        $output = "Data Null!";
    }
}
```

and this is my code to update table:

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])) {
    $Nomor = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Nomor']);

    //query database
    $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor' union SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE Nomor = '$Nomor'");

        $Name = strtoupper($_POST['Name']);
        $Age = strtoupper($_POST['Age']);

        //NEED WORKING CODE HERE
        $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE table1 SET Name ='{$Name}', Age ='{$Age}' WHERE Nomor='$Nomor' union UPDATE table2 SET Name ='{$Name}', Age ='{$Age}' WHERE Nomor='$Nomor'");
        header('Location: going.php');
    }
```

how to make update code work if i want to change search result `b1` Name `Boneng` to `Bonang` or `a2` Age `23` to `27` in for example. sorry if confusing. thx

Comment: Please use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: NOT WORKING is a very poor problem description.

Comment: so any solution how to perform update code for my problem?

Comment: You can't have a `UNION` in an `UPDATE`. Just run it as a separate statement.